# H264 ip camera via gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, ip-camera

I've got web camera (China) which can play MJPEG and h.264. I want to save the stream with gstreamer, but if I can do it with MJPEG, I can't do it with h264. I know, that camera gives h264 stream. Programms from developer shows it and if I save video with such programs I see that it is h264.

```
General
Complete name : C:\RecordFiles\20140319\IPCAM1\20140319_232127_141.avi
Format : AVI
Format/Info : Audio Video Interleave
File size : 4.11 MiB
Duration : 7s 280ms
Overall bit rate : 4 740 Kbps


Video ID : 0
Format : AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile : Baseline@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC : No
Format settings, ReFrames : 1 frame
Codec ID : h264
Duration : 7s 280ms
Bit rate : 4 733 Kbps
Width : 1 280 pixels
Height : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate : 25.000 fps
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.205
Stream size : 4.11 MiB (100%)


Audio ID : 1
Format : PCM
Format settings, Endianness : Little
Format settings, Sign : Signed
Codec ID : 1
Duration : 7s 280ms
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 128 Kbps
Channel count : 1 channel
Sampling rate : 8 000 Hz
Bit depth : 16 bits
Stream size : 114 KiB (3%)
Alignment : Aligned on interleaves
```

So I give all data, if somebody can help to tune gstreamer, I will be glad.
**This works**

```
gst-launch souphttpsrc location="http://shonlinecam1.dyndns.org:81/videostream.cgi?loginuse=user&loginpas=123" \
    ! jpegparse ! jpegdec \
    ! x264enc bitrate=512 key-int-max=45 speed-preset=superfast threads=1 \
    ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au,profile=constrained-baseline \
    ! h264parse ! fakesink
```

**This doesn't work**

```
gst-launch souphttpsrc \
      is-live=true \
      location="http://shonlinecam1.dyndns.org:81/livestream.cgi?user=user&pwd=123&streamid=0" \
    ! h264parse ! decodebin2 ! fakesink
```

All links are real, please help.

Comment: What error do you see in console when it does not work?

Comment: Btw, links are not real anymore. Is it intentional that first one have   `loginuse=user&loginpas=123` but the second one provides `user=user&pwd=123`?